# How to have all errors pointed out instead of one by one

Tags: javascript

Here's the cobbled script. It works as in the minute you leave something blank, it points it out via the submit button. But it's annoying because it points it out one by one instead of right away all fields that are blank.

How do I fix this? Please break it down in bite-size as the bigger goal here is understanding it not just merely making this work.

```js
document.forms[0].onsubmit= function() {
   var form = document.forms[0];
   for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
       if (form.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
           console.log(form.elements[i]);
           form.elements[i].border = "1px solid red"; 
           form.elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
   <div id="validation"></div>
   <p><label>Name<br><input type="text" name="Name"></label></p>
   <p><label>Email<br><input type="email" name="Email" ></label></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: remove `return false;` from inside the for, it is stopping the loop after the first iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` statement is causing the loop to halt early. Just let it run to the end if you want to signal all incomplete fields.

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit= function(event) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
         if (this.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
             event.preventDefault();
             this.elements[i].style.border = "1px solid red"; 
             this.elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
         }
     }
 }
```

---

And here's a more modern way to write it, using a class and newer syntax.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  for (const el of this.elements) {
    if (el.classList.toggle("incomplete", el.value.length == 0)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.incomplete {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
  <div id="validation"></div>
  <p><label>Name<br><input type="text" name="Name"></label></p>
  <p><label>Email<br><input type="email" name="Email" ></label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to teach me the modern way as well. I hadn't realized that. Tried your first script, and it worked. But when I tried your modern script, it didn't work.

Comment: @user273072545345: I forgot to remove the quotes from the CSS. I created a demo above, but it seems that the demo runner doesn't like the arrow function, so a reverted it back to traditional `function` syntax.

Comment: both scripts work now. Thank you. The modern script scares me a little since it seems so foreign to me, ie, not what I've seen online when googling JS validation stuff. What does this line mean `const el of this.elements`?

Comment: @user273072545345: That's a new kind of loop that iterates over anything that implements the Iterator interface. The `el` will be the current item in the loop. The `.toggleClass`, when given one argument, simply adds the class if it's not present, otherwise removes it. But we gave two arguments, so changes the behavior so that it adds the class if a `true` value is passed, otherwise it remove it. It also returns `true` if the class was added, otherwise `false`, so we use that for the condition of the `if` statement.

Comment: thank you for explaining it. Still need to wrap my head around it but will investigate it further.

Comment: `this` is in reference to the argument of `event`, correct?

Comment: @user273072545345: `this` will refer to the element to which you bound the event handler, which in this case is the first `form` element on the page. You can also use `event.currentTarget` to get the same element.

Answer (score 3):

You exit the loop as soon as an input element of the form has a length of `0` :

```
 if (form.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
    .. ..
     return false;
 }
```

The  `return false;` must be located after the loop if at least an input didin't match to your requirements.
You may use a `boolean` variable to store this information.

```
<script>
 document.forms[0].onsubmit= function() {
     var form = document.forms[0];
     var hasError = false;
     for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
         if (form.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
             console.log(form.elements[i]);
             form.elements[i].border = "1px solid red"; 
             form.elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
             hasError = true;
         }
     }

     if (hasError){
       return false;
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: could you fill your latter part out a bit more? I'm still learning JS, and not sure how to use a boolean factor to make the script work

Comment: would you mind explaining how the `hasError = true;` works? I don't understand the need for true and than `return false` later ... sorry, total newbie in JS.

Comment: Of course. 1)As you has an error in at least one of the submitted input, you want that `onsubmit()` returns false so that the form be not submitted.  2) `hasError` is a boolean var that will be true only if at least one of the submitted inputs is not correct. So  only in this case you return false :  `if (hasError){
       return false;
     }`

Comment: so in other words, you need to have `return false` if the form has been filled out perfectly so the script can halt? Thank you for taking the time to explain, btw.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Really appreciate you taking the time to answer. It was really hard choosing both answers.

Comment: You are welcome. It didn't take much time :) Thank you for your vote. If it may help you, you can choose the answer that you will use in your code :)